# How to view the contents of a megafunction RAM from Quartus after simulation

Tags: verilog, quartus

I have a single port RAM mega function that is initialized with a MIF file. I want to view the contents of the RAM after Modelsim simulation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would like to be able to do this as well, but I don't see an obvious way to do it.  If you replace the RAM megafunction with a verilog array (ideally a systemverilog unpacked array) then you can view that in the simulator, and if you do it properly quartus will still infer the correct RAM mega function.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't decode Mega function RTL code.